# Python typing "Invalid type comment or annotation [valid-type]"

Tags: python, mypy, pydantic

I am having some problems defining types for my functions, mypy is complaining with the following error:

```
error: Invalid type comment or annotation  [valid-type]
```

Here is my code:

I have a pydantic basemodel that looks like something like this:

```
class PaginatedResults:
    def __new__(cls, model_to_paginate):
        fields = {
            "data": (typing.List[model_to_paginate], []),
            "limit": (int, DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE),
            "offset": (int, 0),
            "total": (int, 0),
        }
        return create_model(f"Paginated{model_to_paginate.__name__}", **fields)
```

```
class Car(BaseModel):     
    id: int
```

I then use it like so:

```
def my_function(limit: int, offset:int) -> PaginatedResults(Car)
    total=0
    return PaginatedResults(Car)(
            data=[],
            limit=limit,
            offset=offset,
            total=0,
    )
```

and it pretty much works, except the mypy complaints ... Any idea how i can do this properly?

Much appreciated.

Tried a few options from [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html)  and [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#other-uses-of-annotations)  but am probably doing it wrong.

Comment: No, you're not doing it *wrong*, there is just no way to fit dynamic metaprogramming into Python's static type system. You can't express "returns type as determined by calling a function" - calling is runtime, static analysis is static and does not execute any part of your program.

Comment: Ok thanks. I understand better now, won't work with dynamically typed models. I've rewrtiten it to static definition, i ony have like 6 or 7 models that need to be paginated.